# String startswith a particular text

Tags: python, string, pandas, if-statement, twitter

I'm trying to read a csv file and I've to do column operations based on some condition.
Its completely ignoring my if condition and executes else statement.
Its a pain after lot of troubleshooting, i'm unable to rectify it.

**Here is the code:**
*Tweet is my column name for tweets...*

```
inf = pd.read_csv('string.csv')
for r in inf : 
    if "RT @" in inf.Tweet :   
        inf["Engagements"] = 0  
    else : 
        inf["Engagements"] = inf["Favorite_Count"] + inf["Retweet_Count"]

inf.to_csv('string2.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Why doesn't your loop use `r`? BTW, if this is a Pandas question, then you should give it the `pandas` tag.

Comment: @NicholasFlees, no inf['Engagements'] is used to access that particular column...r['Engagements'] gives an error "of string indices must be integers, not str"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the above concise answers, if you want to use a similar if else structure, you can use `set_value` to set the value of a specific row and column.

```
import pandas as pd
inf = pd.read_csv('string.csv')
for index,row in inf.iterrows():
    if "RT @" in row["Tweet"]:
        inf.set_value(index, "Engagements", 0)
    else:
        inf.set_value(index, "Engagements", row["Favorite_Count"] + row["Retweet_Count"])
inf.to_csv('string2.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: thanks pal, i totally forgot about iterrows() method. Its working . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In pandas working with arrays, so need [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with boolean mask created by [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `^` for starts of `string` or use [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
inf["Engagements"] = np.where(inf["Tweet"].str.contains('^RT @'), 
                              0, 
                              inf["Favorite_Count"] + inf["Retweet_Count"])
```

Sample:

```
inf["Engagements"] = np.where(inf["Tweet"].str.contains('^RT @'), 
                              0, 
                              inf["Favorite_Count"] + inf["Retweet_Count"])

print (inf)
   Favorite_Count  Retweet_Count     Tweet  Engagements
0               1              2  RT @ ddd            0
1               4              0        dd            4
2               5              7  dds RT @           12
```

---

```
inf["Engagements"] = np.where(inf["Tweet"].str.startswith('RT @'), 
                              0, 
                              inf["Favorite_Count"] + inf["Retweet_Count"])

print (inf)
   Favorite_Count  Retweet_Count     Tweet  Engagements
0               1              2  RT @ ddd            0
1               4              0        dd            4
2               5              7  dds RT @           12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first initialize your `Engagement` column to zeros.  Then create a mask to find the tweets that *don't start with* 'RT @' (note the `~` negation).  Finally, use the mask to add the `Favorite_Count` and `Retweet_Count` columns.

**Note that you rarely want to use loops with a dataframe.**

```
inf = pd.read_csv('string.csv')

inf['Engagement'] = 0
mask = ~inf.Tweet.str.startswith('RT @')
inf.loc[mask, 'Engagement'] = (
    inf.loc[mask, 'Favorite_Count'] 
    + inf.loc[mask, 'Retweet_Count']
)
```

Example:

```
# Sample data.
inf = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Tweet': ["RT @ something", "something that doesn't start with RT @", "something else"],
     'Favorite_Count': [1, 2, 3], 
     'Retweet_Count': [3, 2, 1]})

# Apply code
inf['Engagement'] = 0
mask = ~inf.Tweet.str.startswith('RT @')
inf.loc[mask, 'Engagement'] = (
    inf.loc[mask, 'Favorite_Count'] 
    + inf.loc[mask, 'Retweet_Count']
)

>>> inf[['Favorite_Count', 'Retweet_Count', 'Engagement', 'Tweet']]
    Favorite_Count  Retweet_Count   Engagement  Tweet
0   1   3   0   RT @ something
1   2   2   4   something that doesn't start with RT @
2   3   1   4   something else
```

Answer (score -1):

`if string.startswith(whateveritshouldstartwith):`

This is the correct way to make this.